# dd'ing images onto an SD card

Tags: linux, sd-card, disk-image, dd

I have a somewhat weird situation I'm trying to `dd` an OS image (something which I dd'ed off a card earlier) onto an SD card.

The card capacity is 8GB and the image was made off an SD card of similar capacity. This is on linux. The image has 2 partitions (/ and /boot). The SD card when inserted is available on `/dev/sdb`. I'm trying to dd the image back onto the card using dd. The command looks like `dd if=image of=/dev/sdb bs=512M`. However, the command fails after 2GB is transferred saying that the disk is out of capacity.

If however, I do `mkfs.ext4` on /dev/sdb with a size of 7GB and then recreate the partition table using gparted and create an actual `/dev/sdb1`, I can successfully dd the image back onto this partition without any problem.

Why is the 2GB error message coming up? And how do I dd the image onto the card?

Comment: It looks as though you are using a 32-bit `dd`: type `file $(which dd)` to check.

Comment: Looks like it's 64 bit. `ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32`

Comment: May or may not relevant to your problem, but bs=512M is silly. Something like 4k or 1M would be good.

Comment: This was just one of the things I tried. The  basic problem is that regardless of the block size, I still get the 2G problem and I don't know how to analyse it.

Comment: SD cards are common targets of forgeries, are you sure the card is genuine? You can verify it with F3 http://oss.digirati.com.br/f3/

Comment: I tried f3 and  it passed fine. This is some kind of mistake on  my end and I can't understand what.

Comment: I am slightly confused: are you saying that you can copy to `/dev/sdb1`, but not to `/dev/sdb`? Even after formatting with `gparted`?

Comment: Yes. That's what confusing me.